# when checkbox checked how to click tags at different div?

Tags: javascript, html

when checkbox are checked,

I want to trigger click of a tag which is download function in same tr tag in order
by click [download start] button.

they are in different << td >> tag each other in the same << tr >> tag

how can i trigger click in order?

do i need to use for statement to click elements in different div in order by checkbox?

```html
<tr>
  <td id="10Mb.dat"><input type="checkbox" data-url="https://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/73000/73751/world.topo.bathy.200407.3x21600x10800.jpg" />File10MB
  </td>
  <td class="test"><a class="checkBtn checkBtn1" id="checkBtn1" onclick="download_file(event, '10Mb.dat')">download</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="100mb.bin"><input type="checkbox" data-url="http://speedtest-ny.turnkeyinternet.net/100mb.bin" />File100MB
  </td>
  <td class="test"><a class="checkBtn checkBtn2" id="checkBtn2" onclick="download_file(event, '100mb.bin')">download</a></td>
</tr>
 <button class="btn btn-primary compress">download start</button>
```

Comment: are you using jquery? can you show your script part..

Comment: dispatchEvent()  => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a css class to your checkbox .

```
$('.checkboxclass').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('td').parents('tr').find('.checkBtn').click();
}
```

To check using the button, iterate through checked checkboxes in the table,

```
$("table.test 
input:checkbox:checked").parents('tr').find("input[name$='.checkBtn']")
.each(function(){
   download(link); //write the code to download file
}
```

Comment: hi, I forgot to add <button> element. could you re-answer my question? I need to click by <button> click

Comment: @g.developer What should happen when you click the button?

Comment: if checkboxes are checked, need to click each checkbox's checkBtn in order